# Hidding/Showing two different tooltips for same div on clicking and hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor tag and on clicking it, I'll be showing a tooltip. Also on hovering it, I'll be showing a different tooltip. The problem here is that when I try to click and have the mouse over the div, I'm getting both the tooltips. IS there any way to fix it using CSS or js?

html :

```
<a href="#" class="infoTip showtooltip" tabindex="0" alt="Current Risk Levels" ng-click="mytoolTip()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"> 
    <span class="infoIconTip">My info</span>
```

css:

```
.showtooltip:hover .infoIconTip, .showtooltip:active .infoIconTip {
    visibility: visible;
}

.showtooltip .infoIconTip {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: auto;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I'm showing the data-toggle tooltip using jQuery:

```
mytoolTip = function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
    myservice.tiggerTooltip();
};
```

I tried to hide the "infoIcontip" using `hide()` jQuery function as well as used .css('visibility','hidden') on clicking it. But, no luck when I hover again I'm unable to get the hover tooltip.

Comment: You should use the same html element for your tooltips

Comment: Could it get you..